# $(document).ready(function() isn't called

Tags: php, jquery

I've set document.ready in the middle of a page.

It was working fine on local server, on an online production beta server, but failed on the final server.

Any suggestions?

thx

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

And yes. JQuery is loading and it's working propely

**UPDATE:** These days I've found the same issue and for futher reference the script tag that includes the jQuery must be propely closed. If not the $(document).ready() is never called.

```
Wrong:
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js'/>

Also wrong:
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js'>

Right:
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js'></script>
```

Nowadays using hmtl5 `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: "Any suggestions" - yes, provide some code.

Comment: Any javascript errors?  What's your jquery library reference look like?

Comment: Did you properly set the script tag as `<script type="text/javascript>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and check:

- is jQuery loading or is it missing. And is it loaded before the `document.ready` ?
- is the script throwing any JavaScript-errors?

Comment: +1 Web development without firebug is like driving blindfolded

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problem is the production server doesn't have a copy of jquery. Switching to having [google provide jquery](http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/) for you is a good practice.

Comment: uh.... no.   Premature optimization.   Just seems bad to rely on an outside source for something so integral to the site.

Comment: @DGM: I'd say if google went down the internet would die, at least temporarily. On the other hand lets say they disabled this service, which caused your site to have some downtime. I'd say the speed benefits and current reliability outweigh that con by far.

Comment: @DGM: Yuriy is right. There is absolutely nothing wrong with using Google CDN's hosted version of jQuery (or any other library for that matter). Also, there's a good chance that the library may be cached on the users computer, making it faster to load and saving bandwidth.